# use play framework 2.0 with oracle 10g

Tags: java, playframework, oracle10g, configuration-files

I try to connect a play framework sample to an oracle 10g db so I use these string connexion :

```
jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.1521:1521:play
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.user=sysdba
db.pass=tongji
```

and put the ojdbc14.jar to the `/lib directory`.
But I get this error :
[image]

I try different things (put `""` at each line, try `localhost` instead of the ip address of my listener, ...) but nothing works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For deafult DB keys are formated with setting's name: `db.default.key-name`.

Try this:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.2.1521:1521:play"
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.default.user=sysdba
db.default.pass=tongji
```

(*of course insert correct URL and credentials, etc, I don't know format of Oracle's connection URL*)